# Root view controller issue for a common scenario in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want my iOS app to follow the common pattern of having a main view where signing up or signing in is required to access the app, so if it is the first time the app is run in the device or the user is not logged in, that is the view displayed, and another app view is displayed otherwise. "Sign up" and "Sign in" buttons in main view may navigate to the corresponding forms, or they may show them modally. Once the user access the app, it should be tab based, similarly to Twitter app.

My question is: what should be my `rootViewController`? A `UINavigationController` where to push the main view if there are no user's credentials, and the `UITabBarController` if there are? Or should I set the `rootViewController` dynamically in the app delegate depending on having credentials or not?

Thanks

Comment: You could just have your main UITabBarController as the root, and in the first page check for login credentials. If they don't have them, present the login viewcontroller modal.

Comment: @Eric I need to present a main view with "Sign in" and "Sign up" buttons and then the form for requesting credentials/user data, instead of presenting directly a sign in view modally

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the second solution, use the login screen as root first and on login, change the rootViewController. You can animate this the same way as a modal presentation is animated.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController` is against  the iOS design philosophy. I'm not sure if you'll get a warning or a black screen but something wrong will definitely happen.

There's no need switching between `rootViewController`.
The `rootViewController` should be the root, in your case that's the `UITabBarController` connecting to the`UINavigationController` or `viewController`with the signup sign in forms. If the credentials are there, just skip that view.

Switching between roots sounds a bit off. What if the user signs off? what if the user has multiple accounts and signing in and out? That's a lot of unneeded switches.

According to Apple recommendation, UITabBarController should always be the root view controller of your app. more Interesting reading:

> When embedding navigation controllers in a tab bar interface, you
>   should embed only instances of the UINavigationController class, and
>   not system view controllers that are subclasses of the
>   UINavigationController class. Although the system provides custom
>   navigation controllers for selecting contacts, picking images, and
>   implementing other behaviors, these view controllers are generally
>   designed to be presented modally. For information about how to use a
>   specific view controller, see the reference documentation for that
>   class.

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html)

Comment: Then if I consider the `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` and I don`t change it even if I already have credentials, I`ll embed the `UITabBarController` in it...

Comment: Obviously I switched between the two. Edited my answer.

Comment: If I keep the `UITabBarController` as the `rootViewController`, can I show the main view with the buttons hidding the tab bar at the bottom?

Comment: Of course. You can always hide the `TabBar` to make it look like a normal view. Open a new question if you are having difficulties doing so.

Comment: So... the point is setting the main view with the "Sign in"/"Sign up buttons" as if it were the view for one of the tab items, but hidding the tab bar? Is this more appropiate than switching the `rootViewController`?

Comment: I'm not aware of the all infrastructure of your app but if you're talking about switching roots and having the `UITabViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController` that's a bad idea to begin with, regardless of the switching part.

Comment: Having the `UINavigationController` for the main view as the root and then pushing the `UITabBarController` in such root after the login action was one of the options I was thinking of, but since you discourage following that pattern, I'm not clear about if it is better to set the 'UINavigationController' as root first, and after login set the `UITabBarController` as the new root, or it should be better to state the `UITabBarController` as root from the beginning and avoid changing it, and embedding the `UINavigationController` to the tab bar controller to perform the login

Comment: I dont know if I'm explaining myself properly... I want the structure of my app to be similar to Twitter, where the main view with "Sign in" and "Sign up" buttons does not show any navigation nor tab bars, but once you have logged in, the app is tab based